# Rearrange a table of values

Tags: java, arrays, excel, export-to-excel

I have a program that takes a variety of values and produces output values after doing a hefty amount of math. I'm going to export the output to Excel.

It is correctly calculating these values, but I'm having trouble formatting it so that Excel can easily make a graph with it. Here's a loop that I have that is printing out the output values:

```
int g = 0;
while( g < AValsArray.length) {
    int p = 0;
    x_Solve = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
    //System.out.println("Solving for y given various x values when a = " + AValsArray[g]);
    while(p < 5) {
        BigInteger solve = (AValsArray[g].multiply(x_Solve)).mod(n);
        //long solve = (((long)(list_Solutions.toArray()[g])*x_Solve) % n);
        System.out.print(x_Solve + "\t" + solve);

        x_Solve = (x_Solve.add(BigInteger.valueOf(2)));
        p++;
    }
    System.out.println("");      
    g++;
}
```

And the output that it is producing is the following:

```
2   12397165724 10797531446 9197897168  75982628810   599862860
2   3999085724  7998171446  11997257168 19995428810   599862860
2   9597805724  5198811446  799817168   103976228810  599862860
2   1199725724  2399451446  3599177168  47989028810   599862860
2   6798445724  13596891446 6398537168  131969828810  599862860
2   12397165724 10797531446 9197897168  75982628810   599862860
2   3999085724  7998171446  11997257168 19995428810   599862860
2   9597805724  5198811446  799817168   103976228810  599862860
2   1199725724  2399451446  3599177168  47989028810   599862860
2   6798445724  13596891446 6398537168  131969828810  599862860
```

I need the first row to become the first column, the next row to become the next column, etc. At the end, our table would have the entire bottom row have the values of 599862860 (at least in this example). The size of the rows and columns are subject to change each time it runs, so these will have to be easily changeable.

Comment: Let me rephrase your problem: you want to print out the transposed array. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose

Comment: You are looking for a simple transposition?  Excel can do this.  You can also generate the data transposed by storing it an array and iterating over it transposed to output it.  Please show what you have tried so far (code).

Comment: @user152468 Wow, I knew there had to be a term for it. Yes, I suppose I'm looking for the easiest way to transpose my data. :)

Comment: Put everything in a guava `Table` and use [`Tables.transpose`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Tables.html#transpose(com.google.common.collect.Table)) is a solution